# Close event for chrome.app.window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When a chrome app window is closed, is it possible to detect the event? and do an action before the window is closed?

Comment: Check here : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885
I think its still not available as an official API.

how ever chrome.windows has onRemoved event `chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer windowId) {...});` 

its still available as an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[chrome.app.window.current().onClosed](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html#event-onClosed) allows you to register an event listener for when a window is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is finally working. Is it a newly added function? because yesterday I checked that documentation page and I am pretty sure the `onClosed` function wasn't there

Comment: Not recently added, but due to a limitation in our documentation system only recently documented :)

Comment: Hmm I registered an onClosed handler but it wasn't able to do any work. chrome.runtime.sendMessage wasn't received by the background page. What is the point of this? Has anyone been able to do anything useful in window.current().onClosed ?

Answer (score 2):

Vincent's answer will work in some cases, but the documentation warns that some chrome api functionality will be lost by the time the onClosed event is fired.

> Note, this should be listened to from a window other than the window
>   being closed, for example from the background page

To listen for this event from the background page, do something like this:

```
chrome.app.window.get(windowIDUsedToCreateChildWindow).onClosed.addListener(function(){...})
```