# onbeforeclose Event for Chrome App Window

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there a way to create an onbeforeclose event after the close button of a chrome app is clicked?

I would like to show a message notifying the user that the window is being closed.

Comment: This question seems identical to the one you asked on March 27 of last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662127/close-event-for-chrome-app-window

Comment: It seems similar but here I am asking for an event that happens before you close the window not after you close the window. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility for doing what you want is to create a window with `frame: "none"`, create a close button in your page and add a function like this in your JS:

```
function quitCloseWindow () { // Called when a user clicks on the close button.
    console.log("Bye."); // What to do just before closing the window.
    chrome.app.window.current().close(); // Closing the window.
}
```

I'm really not a fan of this solution but so far it has been the only one I have found.

Using `frame: "none"` also lets you manage when the window is minimized/maximized, for example I made a project to fix an issue with "maximize" on Windows but it works only without frame: https://github.com/AplusA/Maximize-CPA