# onClosed() not firing when using the X to close a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest, google-chrome-app

Background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  console.log('launched');
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    innerBounds: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      minWidth: 200,
      minHeight: 200,
    }
  });
})

chrome.app.window.onClosed.addListener(function() {
    console.log('close bg');
});
```

mainfest.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "version": "3.4.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    {"socket": [
      "tcp-listen:*:*", 
      "tcp-connect", 
      "resolve-host", 
      "udp-bind:*:*", 
      "udp-send-to:*:*"
    ]}
  ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to detect the closing of the Chrome App window when a user uses the red X. However, the 'close bg' console log never appears, so I take that as it doesn't fire.

What am I missing?

---

I've updated my `.json` to include a background page that is persistent. I thought maybe the bg page was closing to fast for the event to trigger.

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx": "3.4.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    {"socket": [
      "tcp-listen:*:*", 
      "tcp-connect", 
      "resolve-host", 
      "udp-bind:*:*", 
      "udp-send-to:*:*"
    ]}
  ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "page": "background.html",
      "persistent": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the "get" idea by the user below as so:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  console.log('launched');
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
      id:'cci',
    innerBounds: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      minWidth: 200,
      minHeight: 200,
    }
  });
})


chrome.app.window.get('cci').onClosed.addListener(function() {
        console.log('close bg');
});
```

However, on launch I get this error. I don't think the ID is being assigned fast enough so 'cci' is not valid.

[image: js error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach the listener to a specific window for this to work, not to the chrome.app.window global object. The third parameter in the chrome.app.window.create() function allows you to specify a callback that receives the newly created window object as a parameter.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  console.log('launched');
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    innerBounds: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      minWidth: 200,
      minHeight: 200,
    }
  }, function(window){
      window.onClosed.addListener(function() {
        console.log('close bg');
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero

Answer (score 0):

"chrome.app.window.current().onClosed allows you to register an event listener for when a window is closed."

found answer here:
[Close event for chrome.app.window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662127/close-event-for-chrome-app-window)

Edit:
Documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onClosed

States:

> Fired when the window is closed. Note, this should be listened to from a window other than the window being closed, for example from the background page. This is because the window being closed will be in the process of being torn down when the event is fired, which means not all APIs in the window's script context will be functional.

Comment: I've added an eventListener that should output to the console on window close, but it doesn't

Comment: try: "chrome.app.window.get(windowIDUsedToCreateChildWindow).onClosed.addListener(function(){...})"

Comment: documentation is a little misleading. By description *chrome.app.window.current().onClosed* should fire in background for any window (without getting it by ID)...

but that's not the case