# Perform action before Chrome closes itself

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on Chrome extension which needs to perform an action just before Chrome closes. Is there any method like `chrome.window.onClose.addListener(...)`, or `chrome.runtime.onClose.addListener(...)` to ensure that something will be done and then chrome will close itself?

I've been struggling with this problem for two weeks. Here are the options for potential solutions that I've found, but they didn't work.

**My investigation results:**

1. Using function: `chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(...)` - I don't know why, but it doesn't work at all for me. For example, I've tried to write a callback for this event, which tries to add hardcoded data to the indexed DB, but it doesn't add it. Description of this method even says that the callback is not guaranteed to be completed. [OnSuspend documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onSuspend)

> Sent to the event page just before it is unloaded. This gives the extension opportunity to do some cleanup. Note that since the page is unloading, any asynchronous operations started while handling this event are not guaranteed to complete.

2. Chrome working in a background - with this option my extensions seems to work, but... only on Windows older than Windows 10. I've checked few options and on my other computer, which has Windows 7 installed, processes connected to Chrome are closing more slowly, which gives time for my extension to perform necessary tasks. Unfortunately, Windows 10 kills all the processes much faster. I've check option "*continue running background apps when google chrome is closed*", but it doesn't change anything. I've also enabled flag "*#enable-push-api-background-mode*", it hasn't helped either.
   [Keep Chrome running in the background on Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/984062/get-google-chrome-to-run-in-the-background-again-on-windows-10), [Enable flag to keep Chrome processes running](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/k5beS9hndcI)
3. `chrome.app.window.current().onClosed` - I've found a similar question on Stack Overflow, and one of the answers was the code mentioned above. The problem is when I try to type `chrome.app.win...` inside console, it doesn't show any suggestions both in background script and content script. Google's documentation doesn't mention any permission that I've to add inside my manifest.json to get access to this functionality.[Stack Overflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662127/close-event-for-chrome-app-window), [Google's documentation about chrome.app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onClosed)
4. Methods build in web browser - I've thought that method `window.onclose` might be useful in my case. I've performed the same test as for `chrome.runtime.onSuspend`, but the result was exactly the same. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclose)

I've stuck and haven't got any idea how to solve my problem. Maybe I missed something important? Hope you will help me.

Comment: There's no way to detect this event reliably from within the browser and have time to do something, especially async. The only reliable method AFAIK is to have a separate native OS utility that communicates with the extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.

Comment: As said above, Chrome doesn't wait for async handlers on listeners to return before closing, since this could lead to unwanted behaviour of locking or slowing down the process.