# Detect tab close on chrome mobile android browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I tried beforeunload and onunload events but they get called only when user navigate to a different page via address bar not when user close the chrome android browser tab.

I want to send analytics code only when user has closed the page via tab also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662127/close-event-for-chrome-app-window

Comment: I want to detect the same page close event chrome.app.window.current().onClosed  Fired when the window is closed. Note, this should be listened to from a window other than the window being closed, for example from the background page.